# LINQ Contains Syntax with List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I have a List of ids posted with an HTTP post to an *.aspx page. On the server I'm trying to compare that list to a List of objects to see which objects have their PrimaryKey ID field missing from the posted ids (aka deletes) and ids from the List that have no corresponding objects (adds).  Here's my LINQ to get the deletes:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>(txtParticipants.Value.Split(','));
List<NetworkEvent> deletes = e.NetworkEvent.Where(c =>
      !ids.Contains(c.NetworkID.ToString())).ToList<NetworkEvent>();
```

This query for the deletes is working fine.  My problem is generating the converse, the adds.  Here's my attempt (that I need help with).  The question is how do I reference the string from the List in the Contains() predicate?  Obviously c by itself is wrong but how to I reference it?

```
List<string> adds = newids.Where( c=> (e.NetworkEvent.Select
    (z=> z.NetworkID ).Contains( int.Parse(c) ));
```

Hopefully my question makes sense (?!).  thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using LINQ's Except() function.  Example: IEnumerable1.Except(IEnumberable2); would give you all the items in 1 that are not in 2.

Comment: Are the identifiers all pure string data or are they string representations of integers (or another simpler type)?  You should try to avoid searching through string collections whenever possible.  That way you won't have to deal with case-sensitivity, extra whitespace and other such string issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var itemsAlreadyAdded = new int[] { 2, 4, 6 };
var newIds = new string[] { "2", "3" };

var itemsToAdd = newIds.Except(itemsAlreadyAdded.Select(iaa => iaa.ToString()));

foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thx for the Except syntax.  You gave me the conceptual piece I was missing which was the ability to create the "sub-Select" within the Except() method so that the projection contained the strings.  BTW, I also stumbled upon the ConvertAll function so it was helpful to convert my strings to ints before running my Except LINQ syntax.  The snipet looks like this: `            List<int> ids = txtParticipants.Value == "" ? new List<int>() :
                new List<string>(txtParticipants.Value.Split(',')).ConvertAll(i => int.Parse(i));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
List<string> adds = newids.Where(id => !e.NetworkEvent.Any(e => e.NetworkID.ToString() == id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For deletes, you can use "!Contains" as you just did.

For additions, just use the **same expression**, but *in reverse* (i.e. reverse the two lists).

In other words: list #1 !Contains things in list #2 ==>

- item in list #2 deleted from list #1, or
- item in list #2 to be inserted to list #1

So you see the same expression has mirror meanings.

You can also use !Exists or !Any in place of !Contains.